# Dashboard table: get count of subquery

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I've been struggling with this for a few hours.

I am trying to build a simple table that will have the following:

1. Result of a search containing an id and a date
2. Count of a subquery using the id of the search in 1

I have two working queries that achieve what I want individually, but when I try to use a join I lose the data of the query for #2.

Query #1: index= source="" "" AND parentId=1574 | fields childId, date
-> returns 333, 
Query #2: index= source="" "" AND childId=333 | chart count as childCount | fields childCount
-> returns the count, 4 for example

When I try to join the two using something like this, I lose the count:

```
index=<redacted> source="<redacted" "<some query text>" AND 
    parentId=1574 
| fields childId, date
| join type=left childId [ 
    search index=<redacted> source="<redacted>" "<some query text>" AND 
    childId=333 | chart count as childCount | fields childCount
]
| table artifactId, childCount, date
```

I've also tried an outer join, append, etc. to no avail. The count could be 0 as well.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data from the second search is lost because the search does not return the 'childId' field expected by the `join`.  It returns only the 'childCount' field specified in the `fields` command.  Try `fields childId childCount`.